# Laravel task schedular not fully log in aws cloudwatch

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, amazon-cloudwatch

My laravel cron job work fine in my localhost but fail at server. Try to log for more information but failed to do so. My enviroment LOG_CHANNEL=stderr, my controller class have no issue producing log in cloudwatch.

my cron job

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html && sudo -u www-data php artisan schedule:run >> /proc/1/fd/1 2>&1
```

my command

```
    <?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\Subscriber;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Test2 extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:test2';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Test2 Command';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::debug('Command - Test');

        try {
            $subscribers = Subscriber::where('status', Subscriber::PENDING)->get();

            return Command::SUCCESS;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::debug('Command failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return Command::FAILURE;
        }
    }
}
```

log in cloudwatch

```
Running ['artisan' command:test2] ........... 294ms FAIL

⇂ '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' command:test2 > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

I can run php artisan schedule:run in server with no issue
[image]

Another thing I dont understand is why my cron is php artisan schedule:run >> /proc/1/fd/1 2>&1 but command output return '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' command:test2 > '/dev/null' 2>&1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default scheduled tasks (which run as independent processes) output to `/dev/null`. To change this you can use [`sendOutputTo`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#task-output) or similar:

```
$schedule->command('command:test2')
         ->daily() // or whatever
         ->sendOutputTo('/proc/1/fd/1');
```

If you want to do this for all scheduled events you should create an [event listener](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#events) for the starting event and modify the scheduled event there.